# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, debugging

I am trying to parse an xml file using AJAX. Interestingly, when I tried this same code for a different XML file, it worked. If I add an `alert(txt);` right after the `txt = txt + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";` line, it shows the addition of all of the names.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page for XML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo"> This is a test </p>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()"> Click here to request data </button>
<script>

function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp, xmlDoc, txt, x, i;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
    txt = "";
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('sort-name');
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

      txt = txt + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "MemberData.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the link to the XML file.

http://clerk.house.gov/xml/lists/MemberData.xml

Comment: Have you thought to check the length of `x[i].childNodes` first? You can inspect `x[i]` by running `console.log("X i childnodes", x[i].childNodes);` before that line. Then see the output by hitting f12 in your browser. More than likely, while there is an element with tagname sort-name it doesn't necessarily have to have a list of children nodes.

Comment: The error is telling you that for some value of `i`, `x[i].childNodes[0]` is `undefined`.

Comment: @scrappedcola You're right, there was an element with tagname sort-name and length 0. What would be the implications of this in the XML file? Would it be an element "sort-name" with no text node?

Comment: Yea if you do a search of the doc you will find at least one at `statedistrict>OH08</statedistrict>` there is a `<sort-name/>`. It's always the best idea to validate your inputs before you try to work on their possible properties